# Store "variables" without declaring a variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a speaking AI. To do this, I am creating a list of classes for every word (or phrase) in the English language. Kind of like [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org)
has.

Something like this:

```
class english {
    class lemma {
        class adjective {
            class uncomparable { 
                // Word strings here.
        };
    };  
};
```

I was wandering if there is any way to store word strings without declaring millions of different variables for speed and less memory. Any ideas?

Comment: look into `std::map`

Comment: Just look at STL and decide if any of those structures work for your application.

Comment: I will look in to it.

Comment: For one second I thought about a speech-synthesizing AI written in TMP. Scary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a tag type for every word, and manage them using static strings:

```
// class-hierarchy.hpp
#ifndef CLASS_HIERARCHY_HPP
#define CLASS_HIERARCHY_HPP

struct english {
    struct substantives {
        struct House;
        struct Horse;
    };
};

// Optional; to avoid long qualified names.
using House = english::substantives::House;
using Horse = english::substantives::Horse;

template<typename WordTag>
struct WordTraits;

template<> struct WordTraits<House> { static constexpr const char* word = "House"; };
template<> struct WordTraits<Horse> { static constexpr const char* word = "Horse"; };

template<typename TagWord>
constexpr char const* getString()
{ return WordTraits<TagWord>::word; }

#endif // CLASS_HIERARCHY_HPP

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "class-hierarchy.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << getString<Horse>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getString<House>() << std::endl;
}
```

After compilation, the "object code" would be something like:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Horse" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "House" << std::endl;
}
```

since the rest of the process is managed by the compiler.

Yes, it's too verbose, but the "class-hierarchy.hpp" file can be generated with any kind of preprocessor parsing a dictionary file like:

```
// dic.txt
english {
  substantives {
    "House", "Horse"
  };
};
```

That parser can be created, for example, with `bison`. Lastly, isn't a `namespace` hierarchy better as a `class hierarchy`?

Here there's a working sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/100b0604f7cd2ed6

Of course, verbosity can be reduced using the preprocessor:

```
#define WORD(x, y) \
   using y = x; \
   template<> struct WordTraits<y> { \
     static constexpr const char* word = #y; \
   };

struct english {
    struct substantives {
       struct House;
       struct Horse;
    };
};

template<typename WordTag>
struct WordTraits;

WORD(english::substantives::House, House);
WORD(english::substantives::Horse, Horse);
```

Working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f8e7d1490a2c597